# How to Sort Firebase SnapShot by inner Child

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, chat

I have dictionaries in Firebase real-time database. I need to sort the entire dictionaries with an inner child in the dictionary. [image]

I need to query the sort, using timestamp child.

```
 self.ref?.child(FirebaseConstants.main.dbBase).child(getRoom(forUser: id)).queryOrdered(byChild: "timeStamp").observe(.value, with: { (snapShot) in

            print(snapShot)

  })
```

I tried this not working.

Comment: why is not working?

Comment: " self.ref?.child(FirebaseConstants.main.dbBase).child(getRoom(forUser: id)) " will reach upto "10_22" , from there i have to sort by the inner timestamp child.

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know the value of the variables, it's hard to say precise. But say this structure is under `/messages/10_22` then you can query it with:

```
Database.database().reference("messages/10_22").queryOrdered(byChild: "timeStamp").observe(.value, with: { (snapShot) in
    println(snapshot.childrenCount)
    for message in snapshot.children.allObjects as [FIRDataSnapshot] {
       println(message.key+": "+message.value)     
    }
})
```